# How get stats of specific Beanstalkd tube?

Tags: php, statistics, beanstalkd

I want to get statistique of `email` tube 
This is my code :

```
$queue = new Phalcon\Queue\Beanstalk(array('host' => 'xxx.xx.x.x','port' => '11300'));

$queue->choose('email');
$queue->watch('email');
$statTube=statsTube('email');
```

I tried to remplace `statsTube` by `stats_tube` but it doesn't work.

I have this error :  `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function statsTube()`

What is my error? I don't understand!

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 1):

Call it from the object, as it's a method of the class.

```
$statTube=$queue->statsTube('email');
```